# Javascript lock service

Tags: web-services, web, locking

I have a page which accesses Google spreadsheets. I want to be sure that multiple users don't change the sheet at the same time, however my page is just using front-end javascript with no real server component. The obvious solution is to use a lock, but without a server API to provide the lock, I'm not sure how this would work.

Are there any services which would let me do locking without needing to set up something on the server?

Answer (score 0):

While not fool-proof at all and not an elegant solution, you can try using a known cell on the spreadsheet as a type of mutex. In pseudocode:

```
cell_A: name/id of user, or just a True/False value to specify that an edit is taking place
cell_B: date/time of last update attempt, preferably in UTC

if cell_A is False:
    change cell_A to True (or update with current_user_name)
    change cell_B to current_date_time
    start editing the rest of the spreadsheet
else:
    if cell_B < (current_date_time - acceptable_threshold): //assume prior edit session timed out or another way the edit was left incomplete, so we're OK to continue
        change cell_A to True (or update with current_user_name)
        change cell_B to current_date_time
        start editing the rest of the spreadsheet
    end if  
end if

callback edits_completed:
    change cell_A to False
```

So you'll still be using a centrally stored token, just managed via Google Sheets. Good luck!